# Youtube Thumb with duration text overlay

Tags: android, image, overlay

I'd like to achieve an ImageView just like on this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ax4iH.jpg): text on an image thumbnail.
Does anyone have some advise on that.

Also i'd like to know if this is an easy task for a device. I'm presenting it in a listview of 100+ items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the ImageView inside relative layout and add TextView on top of it | bottom right.

See here: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html

Comment: yeeha, that is the thing i was looking for: great